# How to hide html file on checkout for certain condition?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to hide checkbox if amount is 0 otherwise show.

I tried,
In html template

```
  <!-- ko if: isAllowed -->
  <div data-bind="visible: checkBalanceAmount()">
            <!-- ko ifnot: isApplied() -->
            <input type="checkbox" id="apply-credit"
                    class="action"
                    data-bind="click: applyCredit">
                    <label for="apply-credit"><!-- ko i18n: 'Use Store Credits' --><!-- /ko --></label>
                <span></span>                
            <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

In js file

```
  checkBalanceAmount: function (amount) {
        if(amount > 0)
            balance_amount = 'success';
        else
            balance_amount = '';
        return balance_amount;                        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return boolean value to show/hide your condition,

**visible consider boolean value to work as expected for ko.**

```
checkBalanceAmount: function (amount) {
        if(amount > 0)
            balance_amount = true;
        else
            balance_amount = false;
        return balance_amount;                        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code u are using an string as boolean which is not acceptable. You need to change the return type of your js function from string to boolean and then in data-bind, visible will get the input as true or false and will work accordingly.